# Getting the property of an associative array given as an escaped string

Tags: node.js, pug

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[{"x": "someValue", 
  "y" : "{\"iWantThisValue\":\"a\", \"otherVal2\":\"b\"}"}]
```

I want to get the value of `"iWantThisValue"`. On the view, I have `#{JSON.parse(myArray.y)}`. If I try to put something like `.iWantThisValue` after it, nothing is printed out. Is this a correct step to getting it? Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close, but you need to subscript the array.

```
var myArray = [
    {
        "x": "someValue", 
        "y" : "{\"iWantThisValue\":\"a\", \"otherVal2\":\"b\"}"
    }
];

console.log( JSON.parse( myArray[0].y ).iWantThisValue );
```

Logs `a`.

Of course in real code, you probably wouldn't just be doing `[0]` to access an array element, but would probably be looping through the array? Either way, you'd still need to use `myArray[index]` where index is `0` in this example.

Also, in the interest of clarity, JavaScript does not have anything called an "associative array". It has arrays and it has objects. In your example, `myArray` is an array of one element. That element is an object which has `x` and `y` properties.